# Not getting data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

am creating one project am using angularjs. I want to get the data from database.i had try this code but we are not getting the data also not getting any error in console. after put the debugger in javascript its successfully run

so please give your feedback.

in my controller am using the code

```
public JsonResult userList()
    {
        dBase dal = new dBase();
        var userlist = dal.GetAllUsers("0");
        return Json(userlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

<link href="~/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/js/AngularJS.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/js/Module.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/Service.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/WolskiDevJ.js"></script>      

in module
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

in Service.js

    app.service("myService", function ($http) {
    this.getAlluser = function () {
        debugger;
        try {
            return $http.get("users/userList");
        }
        catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    };
});

in WolskiDevJ.js

    app.controller("UserCntrl", function ($scope, myService) {
    getalluserlist();
    function getalluserlist() {
        debugger;
        var getuserdata = myService.getAlluser();
        debugger;
        getuserdata.then(function (usr) {
            $scope.userlist = usr.data;
        }, function () { alert('get error') });
    };
});

in view am using the code like 

    <script src="~/js/AngularJS.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="~/js/Module.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/Service.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/WolskiDevJ.js"></script>

    <div class="static_pages home" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="UserCntrl">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th width="8%">Name</th>
                                                                <th width="20%">Email</th>
                                                                <th width="12%">Username</th>
                                                                <th width="14%">Access</th>
                                                                <th width="8%">Status</th>
                                                                <th width="6%">Edit</th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr ng-repeat="userlist in ulist">
                                                                <td>{{userlist.first_name}} </td>
                                                            </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<tr ng-repeat="userlist in ulist">
     <td>{{userlist.first_name}} </td>
</tr>
```

type

```
<tr ng-repeat="myUser in userlist">
     <td>{{myUser.first_name}} </td>
</tr>
```